# how to map through an array of objects in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to access the users via redux

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.user.userdata
})
```

and when I do

```
console.log(this.props.user)
```

I get an array of two objects data and status

```
data: Array(2)
0: {id: 1, name: "kayondo"}
1: {id: 2, name: "syphat"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
status: 200
```

but when i try to map through the data key by

```
this.props.user.data.map(x => (<div>{x.name}</div>}
```

i get an error `undefined` in the console
`? How can I solve this`

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(this.props.user.data)`? What is the full error message from the console?

Comment: What do you mean an "array of 2 objects?"  Is ```this.props.user``` itself an array, or are you just referring to ```data```?  It's tough to tell the entire data structure from what you posted.

Comment: Are you making an api call when the component is rendered? this sounds like maybe `this.props.user.data` doesn't exist until after the api call is resolved.  If this is the case you need a conditional render
`const { data } = this.props.user;
if (data && data.length) {
  // map here
}`

Comment: @AaronRoss yes it true I get two responses as the first is an empty array and the second one has an array with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the right syntax to map. Try using this one:

```
this.props.user.data.map(x => (<div>{x.name}</div>));
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
this.props.user.map(x => (<div>{x.name}</div>)
```